# OpenLayers 6.1.1 add layer to existing layer group in ol-layerswitcher

Tags: layer-switcher, openlayers

I have a productive site with OpenLayers 4.6.4 and want to switch to the actual  6.1.1 version.
Since there where changes in the code I have to adapt mine to get everything work again.

Actually I'm having problem to add layers to an already defined layer group with the actual version of OpenLayers (6.1.1) and the ol-layerswitcher from walkermatt.

Only the group name (Overlay) shows up, but the layers (parzellen and topo54) aren't visible.

Here the code:

```
function init() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

    var toplayers = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Overlay',
        fold: 'open',
        combine: false,
        layers: []
    });


// ------------ Baselayers ---------------
//
    var baselayers = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Hintergrund-Layer',
        fold: 'close',
        layers: [

        new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'OSM',
                type: 'base',
                baseLayer: true,
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.OSM(
                {
                attributions: [
                        '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org" target="_blank">OpenstreetMap</a> OpenstreetMap'
                    ]
                    })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'ACT Hybrid',
                baseLayer: true,
                type: 'base',
                visible: false,
                extent: [636757.681558, 6351042.69913, 728716.389785, 6478379.8966],
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'https://wmts3.geoportail.lu/opendata/service?',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'hybrid',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
                        'TRANSPARENT':false
                    },
                    attributions: [
                        '<a href="https://data.public.lu" target="_blank">data.public.lu</a> Hybrid @ ACT Luxembourg'
                    ],
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            })
        ]
    });

// -------  Map ----------------
//

    var view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([6.2, 49.6]),
        zoom: 12,
        enableRotation: false
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        view: view,
        controls: ol.control.defaults({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: true }}).extend([
            new ol.control.Zoom(),
            new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
            new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
                tipLabel: 'Legende', // Optional label for button
                groupSelectStyle: 'children' // Can be 'children' [default], 'group' or 'none'
            })
        ]),
        layers: [baselayers, toplayers],
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
            new ol.interaction.Select({
                layers: [baselayers, toplayers]
            })
        ])
    });

//-----------  define top-layers ---------------
//
           var parzellen = new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Parzellen',
                visible: true,
                opacity: 0.5,
                extent: [636757.681558, 6351042.69913, 728716.389785, 6478379.8966],
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'https://wmts3.geoportail.lu/opendata/service?',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'cadastre'
                    },
                    attributions: [
                        '<a href="https://data.public.lu" target="_blank">data.public.lu</a> Ortho 2016 &copy ACT Luxembourg'
                    ],
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            });

            var topo54 = new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Carte Topographique 1954',
                visible: true,
                opacity: 0.5,
                extent: [636757.681558, 6351042.69913, 728716.389785, 6478379.8966],
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'https://wmts3.geoportail.lu/opendata/service?',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'TOPO_CARTESHISTO_1954'
                    },
                    attributions: [
                    '<a href="https://data.public.lu" target="_blank">data.public.lu</a> Carte topographique 1954 &copy ACT Luxembourg'
                    ],
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            });


// ------------------ add layers to layerGroups toplayers  ----------
// 
    toplayers.getLayers().push(parzellen, topo54);
//    toplayers.setLayers(new ol.Collection([parzellen,topo54])); this doesn't work as well

} // End function init()

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```